# How print multiple independent pages in one print job?

Tags: linux, firefox, printing

How can I combine multiple single page prints into a single print job?

For example, using Firefox on Linux one can print a web page such that each sheet of paper has four pages printed upon it. I would like to combine several separate web pages so that for example,  web-page-a, web-page-b and web-page-c (each less than one print page long) are printed on a single sheet of paper.

I would like to do this without having to use some form of image editor to combine and manage manually created temporary files.

Answer (score 5):

The way I do it:

- Print all web pages to separate PDFs (single page per sheet!)
- Use pdftk to join the PDFs: `pdftk print1.pdf print2.pdf cat output out.pdf`
- Use a PDF viewer to print `out.pdf` with 4 pages per sheet

It's a little bit cumbersome, but it works.